# CSS: Background images/colors and containers dont stretch full width on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

View on Mobile: http://goo.gl/vkhb0

On all desktop browsers and multiple resolutions the website displays as it should. The top slider images are centered and 1500px wide. The container wrappers below are 960px wide and also centered. Some sections have background images or colors which repeat full width left to right.

On Mobile - The containers below the slideshow don't expand the full width. Likewise the background images that repeat stop about one-third of the screen.

This is a Wordpress website and I already have viewport meta in the header file.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) ie:

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
 /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to determine why the background images stop at one-third width on mobile. A media query wouldn't solve that, as its already set to repeat.

Comment: @user1522087 your wrapper is still 960px on portrait of ipad

Comment: Correct, but this still does not solve the issue. I just tested again to verify, by increasing the container width the background colors/images still stop before meeting the width of the container. So even by increasing the width, the background images and colors still stop before reaching the edge of the container. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: when removed 960px and width property from the wrapper it looked better, why would increase the width?

Comment: I dont have a tablet in front of me, so I cant see how it displays on a tablet but on an iphone modifying the wrapper width does nothing to solve the issue. The slide show above is larger then the container, so increasing it would be the only logical thought since it already doesnt reach the full width of the page.

Comment: Use this [tool](http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/) for testing different sizes it uses viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to simulate different device sizes

Comment: When I view this on desktop or mobile the content below the slideshow does not look centered. The slideshow is 1500px and the content is 960px, so I think it doing whats its supposed to. You have 540px of empty space there on the right.